# Searching an ArrayList for employee number

Tags: java, search, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [search in java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985229/search-in-java-arraylist)

If I have an `ArrayList` of employee objects and each object contains a string: `employeeName` and long: `employeeNumber`.

How do I search the list for an employee given their employee number and return the employee object?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: You can either write your own filter or do iterative search and match yourself.

Comment: you compare them, and then return the object :)

Comment: wow @KevinEsche, it does make sense. :)

Comment: @BlackHatShadow yes it does, it´s the most simple answer to this question, without any code

Comment: @KevinEsche, high five! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines. But it could be better to put the objects in a `HashMap<Long,Employee>` where long is the id, and Employee is the employee belonging to that id.

```
public Employee getEmployeeById(long empId){
    for(Employee e : employeeList) {
        if(e.getId() == empId){
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if OP needs to do a lot of look ups `HashMap` is better.

Comment: You are missing a return statement.

Comment: `return null` after the for loop would fix it.

Comment: @Marcelo you are right, I quicly wrote that without thinking. Fixed my answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use to use `Map<int,string>` where int will serve you for employee number and string for their name so it will be easy and efficient to iterate over this type of collection

Answer (score 0):

```
public class emp {
    int id ;
    String name;
    public emp(int i, String name) 
    {
        super();
        this.id = i;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

///////////

public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                int givenEmpId = 3;
                ArrayList<emp> empList = new ArrayList<emp>();
                empList.add(new emp(1,"hussain1"));
                empList.add(new emp(2,"hussain2"));
                empList.add(new emp(3,"hussain3"));
                  for ( emp currEmp : empList)  
                        {  
                            if(currEmp.id==givenEmpId)
                            {
                                System.out.println("emp name is===>>"+currEmp.name);
                            }
                        }
            }
}
```