# java ArrayList search methods

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which contains a list of `Train`s:

```
package train;

public class Train {

    private String nom;
    private String villeDepart, villeArrivee;

    public Train() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Train(String nom, String villeDepart, String villeArrivee) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.villeDepart = villeDepart;
        this.villeArrivee = villeArrivee;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getVilleDepart() {
        return villeDepart;
    }
    public void setVilleDepart(String villeDepart) {
        this.villeDepart = villeDepart;
    }
    public String getVilleArrivee() {
        return villeArrivee;
    }
    public void setVilleArrivee(String villeArrivee) {
        this.villeArrivee = villeArrivee;
    }
}
```

I want to search the `ArrayList` by `villeDepart` and `villeArrivee`. How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985229/search-in-java-arraylist for solutions (basically you'll need to walk the whole list with a "for" looking for a match).

Comment: Override the equals method in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can think of, you have to use a loop and go through whole list.

```
for each (Train train in list) {
  String villeDepart = train.getVilleDepart();
  String villeArrivee = train.getVilleArrivee();

  if (villeDepart.equals("String you want to match") && villeArrivee.equals("Next String to match") {
    //You got your train
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Atri mentioned, you can Override your equals method. It's much easier.
In your `Train` class,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  Train train = (Train) obj;
  if (this.villeArrivee.equals(train.getVilleArrivee()) && this.villeDepart.equals(train.getVilleDepart())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Read [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) in SO.

Comment: Using a foreach loop like `for (Train t : trainList) { ... t.getVilleDepart() ... }` is more elegant...

Comment: Thanks. I'll update this.

Comment: thinks brothers but i to write a method which returns a list of trains: like this:  public List <Train> getTrains(String villeDepart, String villeArrivee){} how can i do this with an arrayList

Comment: As I mentioned in my code `//You got your train` - you can do whatever you want. Create an `ArrayList`  in the beginning of your method (before `for each` loop), then add your train into the newly created ~ArrayList`. Return it later.